# unable to trigger click event using jQuery .trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I am having some trouble in triggering a click event .

I have html something like this :

```
<div class="carousel-control" >
<a href='#' id="carousel_1">1</a>
<a href='#' id="carousel_2">2</a>
<a href='#' id="carousel_3">3</a>
<a href='#' id="carousel_4">4</a>
<a href='#' id="carousel_5">5</a> 
etc
</div>
```

Now Here is the JS

```
jQuery('.carousel-control a').bind('click', function() {
        alert("carousel cliced")
        return false;
      });

$('#nextimg').click(function() {

var car_index=2;
                $('#carousel_'+(car_index+1)).trigger('click');
alert("next image clicked");
               return false;
            });
```

Now when I manually click the href tag the alert("carousel clicked") appers, 
but when I click the nextimg only next image alert appears not the carousel alert.

I tried using

```
 $('#carousel_2').trigger('click'); 
 $('#carousel_2').click();
 $('#carousel_2').triggerHandler('click');
```

There seems to be no error in the firebug too.

Can someone please help me out. :)
Thank you,

Comment: `var car_inedx=2;` typo?

Comment: nope , sorry the typing error was only here . not in my code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using

```
 $('.carousel-control a').bind('click', function()
```

instead of this

```
jQuery('.carousel-control a').bind('click', function()
```

Works well.

But can anyone explain me why is it happening so ?

Comment: At least if it was the other way round I would think there is some conflict with the '$' But this one is strange ?

Comment: The problem was due to loading the jquery twice in the webpage.!!
figured out after a month.!!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain... but any chance it has to do with your spelling of `index` in `var car_inedx=2;`? (I make mistakes like this often enough myself.)

Comment: nope , sorry the typing error was only here . not in my code :)

Comment: @genesis thank you will keep that in mind, but the problem is that half of my code is generated by ruby , so couldn't copy  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#carousel_'+(car_index+1)).click();
```

instead of

```
$('#carousel_'+(car_index+1)).trigger('click');
```

Comment: you should check why the example @Dogbert gave you works in `jsfiddle` and compare it with yours

Comment: Yup . Can you check my answer too ? and let me know more ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in `var car_inedx`.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rBFxu/

Comment: nope , sorry I made a typing error while typing the question . not in my code :)

Comment: Yeah , then it seems some other problem , I must dig into my code, will update you thanks

Answer (score 0):

Keep the click event under "Document Ready event".

Here it goes like this :

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
      jQuery('.carousel-control a').bind('click', function() {
         alert("carousel cliced")
         return false;
       });

       $('#nextimg').click(function() {
             var car_index=2;
             $('#carousel_'+(car_index+1)).trigger('click');
             alert("next image clicked");
             return false;
       });
});
```